# Disabling typing on mui datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

i need to disable manual entering of the dates on my datepicker i used preventdefault but its not working this is my code

```
         <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                      <DatePicker
                        id="leaveExtensionDate"
                        value={leaveExtensionElements.leaveExtensionDate}
                        shouldDisableDate={isDiabled}
                        onKeyDown={(e) => {
                          e.preventDefault();
                        }}
                        views={["year", "month", "day"]}
                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                        onChange={handleLeaveExtensionDateChange}
                        error={
                          leaveExtensionElements.errorStatus
                            .leaveExtensionDate
                        }
                        helperText={
                          leaveExtensionElements.errorText
                            .leaveExtensionDate
                        }
                      />
                    </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `onKeyDown` event to `preventDefault` to the `TextField` instead of `DatePicker`

```
const onKeyDown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
};

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker
    id="leaveExtensionDate"
    value={leaveExtensionElements.leaveExtensionDate}
    shouldDisableDate={isDiabled}
    views={["year", "month", "day"]}
    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
    onChange={handleLeaveExtensionDateChange}
    error={leaveExtensionElements.errorStatus.leaveExtensionDate}
    helperText={leaveExtensionElements.errorText.leaveExtensionDate}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField onKeyDown={onKeyDown} {...params} />
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

Comment: tried this but not working